# How do I automatically copy data when attaching external storage?

Tags: windows-xp, batch, automation, xcopy, events

If I am correct to assume that once I place a DVD/disk in my optical drive (or use a USB flash drive or external HDD for that matter; for arguments sake) that this action would in effect trigger an 'event' in Windows.

I would like to use this 'triggered event' to enable an entire copy of that device.

Example:

```
if my optical H: reads a disk OR the user closes the tray OR ...
then xcopy /S H: "F:\Copy of H"
```

ADDED: I am working with Windows XP; if any one could give me more of a push in the right dirrection that would help; I don't see how the autorun could help me; do I need to write some script for the autorun to use once this event is triggered?  Or a program?  Not sure what to do, thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Super User! You can't explicitly ask for a programmer as we're a site meant for Super User, programmers can use Stack Overflow BUT your question is sufficiently on-topic on our site so there is no need to create another question there. Good luck on getting an answer... :-)

Comment: Upgrade to a current version of Windows. Then you can trivially create a scheduled task on the corresponding event.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [VBScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t0aew7h6%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) (and other languages that use COM objects) with the [FileSystemObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6kxy1a51%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) and its [Drives](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/832c8c0x%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) property.

You would check the Drives object regularly for new drives (with a `for` statement) and then do something for each drive matching the criteria.

Then you can use the program execution functions from [Windows Script Host](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d1et7k7c%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to run a batch file to copy the files; or you can copy the files in the same drive detection script.

[Here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=01592c48-207d-4be1-8a76-1c4099d7bbb9&displaylang=en) is a very useful help CHM for Microsoft's vbscript and jscript.

Comment: I really like what you posted; but I am totally preocupied right now building a whole new inventory/invoice/quote system for my friends business I wonder if I can burden you to help out some more as you seem to know what you are talking about if you could say write me an 'instruction book' I don't have the time to learn a whole new technology perse on this but I can put in the time to do it myself if I have some clear dirrection; I appologize for this and would greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Best i can find is autorun.</strike>

i know autorun is disabled by default on writable (i.e. USB, but not CD/DVD) media; but i also know that somewhere in the machine security policy (secpol.msc) is the option to reenable it.

Windows 7 completely removed the ability to have AutoPlay on writable media. You're not even allowed to have an option appear on the dialog.

That's because [millions of users would see the following dialog](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/e7/improvements-to-autoplay), and think clicking **Open folder to view files** is harmless:

[image]

That's because they're running `Open folder to view files.exe`.

Comment: You may also need to fiddle with antivirus settings, as this could be interpreted as virus-ey behavior.

Comment: ok that gives me a starting point; are you able to offer me any more information? - Thank you!